# journalctl -u sshd.service command returns 'no entries'

Tags: server, systemd, sshd, systemd-journald

I am currently working on Ubuntu 20.04 machine. When I am running the command `journalctl -u sshd.service`, I am getting the below response.

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2022-12-21 13:01:52 UTC, end at Fri 2023-03-31 15:10:32 UTC

-- No entries -- .
```

But, when I am running `journalctl -u ssh.service`, I am getting the log entries. since `sshd.service` and `ssh.service` are different systemd units, why it is not giving any entries for `journalctl -u sshd.service` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least in the default Ubuntu + OpenSSH implementation, `sshd.service` and `ssh.service` are in fact not different units - the former is an *alias* for the latter, defined in the `[Install]` section of its unit file, `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

Such aliases are discussed in the `DESCRIPTION` section of `man systemd.unit`, and essentially work by creating symbolic links - in this case,

```
$ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Feb 16  2022 /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service -> /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
```

allowing you to start / stop / query the status of the service via `systemctl` using either `ssh.service`, or `sshd.service` (or even just `ssh` or `sshd`).

So what you are observing is that `journalctl` apparently doesn't resolve these systemd aliases - there's some discussion of why and whether it should in [Issue #11846: Journalctl working with Systemd Alias (in Install section)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11846) and also a related (but not satisfactorily answered) question on our sibling site, [How to use systemd aliases with journalctl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392369/how-to-use-systemd-aliases-with-journalctl)